# Mock Laravel Cashier's checkout method on the Billable trait

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, mockery, laravel-cashier

In my API I am getting the checkout url from Stripe using Laravel 11 Cashier 15 and
returning it to the front end to redirect the user.

```php
$response = $user->newSubscription($name, $price)
    ->trialUntil(Carbon::now()->addDays(7)->addMinutes(1))
    ->allowPromotionCodes()
    ->checkout([
        'success_url' => $successUrl,
        'cancel_url' => $cancelUrl,
        'consent_collection' => [
            'terms_of_service' => 'required',
        ],
    ]);
    return $response->url;
```

The User class is using the [Billable](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/15.x/src/Billable.php) trait which uses the [PerformsCharges](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/6c304574e3ec6d3cd22abf18c1f8a4c61ba385ea/src/Concerns/PerformsCharges.php#L138) trait which has the [checkout](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/6c304574e3ec6d3cd22abf18c1f8a4c61ba385ea/src/Concerns/PerformsCharges.php#L138) method which returns the [Checkout](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/15.x/src/Checkout.php) class.

I am trying to mock this for a test using PHPUnit 10.

I have tried

```php
$mock = Mockery::mock(User::class)->makePartial();
$mock->shouldReceive('checkout')
    ->andReturn('https://chicken.com');
```

```php
$mock = Mockery::mock(User::class)->makePartial();
$mock->shouldReceive('allowPromotionCodes->checkout')
    ->andReturn('https://chicken.com');
```

```php
$mock = Mockery::mock(User::class)->makePartial();
$mock->shouldReceive('newSubscription->trialUntil->allowPromotionCodes->checkout')
    ->andReturn('https://chicken.com');
```

without any luck. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? My skills with Mockery are pretty much Google based.

## Edit

I have also tried these to no avail.

```
$subscriptionBuilderMock = Mockery::mock(SubscriptionBuilder::class);

$subscriptionBuilderMock->shouldReceive('trialUntil')
  ->andReturnSelf();

$subscriptionBuilderMock->shouldReceive('allowPromotionCodes')
  ->andReturnSelf();

$checkoutResponse = new stdClass;
$checkoutResponse->url = 'https://chicken.com';

$subscriptionBuilderMock->shouldReceive('checkout')
  ->andReturn($checkoutResponse);

$userMock = Mockery::mock(User::class)->makePartial();

$userMock->shouldReceive('newSubscription')
    ->with($product, $price)
    ->andReturn($subscriptionBuilderMock);
```

And

```
$subscriptionBuilderMock = Mockery::mock(SubscriptionBuilder::class);

$subscriptionBuilderMock->shouldReceive('trialUntil->allowPromotionCodes->checkout')
  ->andReturn($checkoutResponse);
  
$userMock = Mockery::mock(User::class)->makePartial();

$userMock->shouldReceive('newSubscription')
    ->with($product, $price)
    ->andReturn($subscriptionBuilderMock);
```

Comment: looks like nothing will work because Cashier is not using the Laravel Container to resolve dependencies, but it is using static calls and the `new` keyword... the only thing I have in mind is that if you partially mock `User` and then mock `newSubscription`,  because after that point, there is no way for you to get in between. I do see that you tried this, but it did not work. I should check the source code way more, but my recommendation is going to be to move these tests to an `Integration` namespace (instead of `Feature`) and use a sandbox Stripe token so you do the real call to a sandbox

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thanks for the comment. I am investigating that path. I updated my question to reflect the latest attempts. It works when I hit the sandboxed Stripe, the tests just take forever. I have my core Stripe tests which test the integration but only run those when I update anything related.

Comment: As I said before, `newSubscription` is returning `new SubscriptionBuilder($this, $type, $prices);`, you cannot mock it because it is using `new`, so Laravel cannot return anything else than the real object. You can try faking `newSubscription`, and I see you did try it out, what was the error or what happened with it? And yes, it will take more time because it is doing the real API call, just using a sandbox token so it does not change or modify production data, that is why I said to move it to another namespace and run them manually, or always on PRs, but not locally (unless code changed)

Comment: @matiaslauriti I thought about that but the `userMock` mocks `newSubscription` so in theory it shouldn't ever hit `new SubscriptionBuilder` and the `userMock` should return the `subscriptionBuilderMock`. The only thing I can think is that the `User` model uses the `Billable` trait which has the `ManagesSubscriptions` trait. I'll look into that. By the way there are no errors, the test just runs hitting the actual objects, if I add `->once()` it fails with the mock was not called.

Comment: I cannot remember if you may need to mock what `SubscriptionBuilder` is returning, like you should mock the mock the mock of another mock, but that is too much

Comment: @matiaslauriti lol, thanks for your help with this. I'll give the mockety-mock-mock a go.

Comment: That did help me in the past, and I was baffled why it worked, but it did